# Remove %20 from url

Tags: php, yii

I want  to remove %20 from url , thi sis my url i have tried for this url

```
urldecode($url);
```

and this link i wnat to open in href link,like `<a href="$url">`

```
http://localhost/site/steps/providerdetails/Facility-in-715 MORAGA ROAD-MORAGA-MORAGA RETREAT CARE
```

Comment: send query string without spaces

Comment: I guess if you wanted to re-write internet standards and the RFC, then yes, you could put a space in a URI. However, if you don't feel like changing the way the entire internet works, **then perhaps simply don't put spaces in your URIs.**

Comment: @Marty It's not off-topic if you read it for what the question is actually asking (rather than what it says it's asking).... "Why can I not have a URL with spaces in it?"

Comment: @Brad Yeah it's a massive grey area, butI know it will come to being closed either way so I wanted to give people a close option that at least made sense (vs typical mashing of 'unclear what you're asking').

Comment: @Marty Why should this question be closed?  It's as clear as day and perfectly on-topic.

Comment: @Brad I want to this type of url for SCO requirement

Comment: @gouravsharma Can you elaborate on what you mean by SCO requirement?  And, did you read my answer where it says it's not possible?

Answer (score 3):

Spaces in URLs must be encoded as `%20`.  That's how URLs work.  There is no way around it.

For a full list of what needs to be encoded in URLs:  http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

Answer (score 0):

As commenters said, there is a reason `%20` is there.
It's a substitute for a space, as space can not be in URLs by definition.

You can workaround it like this, though.
**It will ONLY work if you do `mod_rewrite`**
The idea is to replace the spaces with something else
And then when you need to use that — replace them back.

```
$url = url_encode( str_replace(' ', '_', $url) );
```

And then, in the target script itself replace them back.

```
$url = str_replace('_', ' ', $url);
```

Comment: Sorry, but i want to see the space in url  like  http://localhost/site/steps/providerdetails/Facility-in-715 MORAGA ROAD-MORAGA-MORAGA RETREAT CARE

Comment: But this is impossible :) URLs can't have spaces in them. That's it.